# Set Taskbar position Win7 c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to set the taskbar position/width/height using the windows API?
I'm running 3 monitors and I want to prevent the taskbar from spanning across all monitors and not stay on top all the time.

Here is what I have attempted so far with no luck... I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my code or it's just being blocked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    int getTaskBarHeight();
    void setTaskBarPos();
};

int MyClass::getTaskBarHeight()
{
    RECT rect;
    HWND taskBar = FindWindow(L"Shell_traywnd", NULL);
    if(taskBar && GetWindowRect(taskBar, &rect)) {
        return rect.bottom - rect.top;
    }
}

void MyClass::setTaskBarPos()
{
    RECT rect;
    HWND taskBar = FindWindow(L"Shell_traywnd", NULL);
    if(taskBar && GetWindowRect(taskBar, &rect)) {

        SetWindowPos(taskBar, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 1080, 46, SWP_NOZORDER);

    }
}

int main(void)
{
    MyClass taskbar;
    cout << taskbar.getTaskBarHeight();

    taskbar.setTaskBarPos();

    int a;
    cin >> a;
}
```

Comment: If there's no way to constrain it as you want through the usual settings/control panel areas of Windows, I doubt there's a programmatic interface that's appropriate - having arbitrary programs interfere with the taskbar wouldn't be a good general experience.

Comment: This comment is off-topic but it looks like you don't have got the concept of classes right. the window handle should be a member variable of the class MyClass rather than a local variable in a member function.

Comment: Did you find the handle in taskBar?

Comment: They weren't classes to begin with and must have forgot to change the variables when I added the class. No biggie for now.

I get the handle fine as it returns the height in my get height function.

Comment: Setting SWP_HIDEWINDOW or SWP_SHOWWINDOW actually hides/shows the taskbar so its the right handle for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the "Spanning accross all 3 displays" question, this is normally down to the configuration of the display adapter. You can have 3 individual displays (1 per monitor), or 1 big display spanning accross all three monitors. The latter sounds like your situation, and Windows offers no way to make an app bar only take up part of a display.

Your best bet is to adjust the display driver to create 3 indiividual displays rather than 1 big one.

Comment: the SLi options (beta ) in the nVidia control panel actually resizes and moves the start bar, not sure how they are doing it. But it locks it into place in the centre and has been causing issues with fill screen apps.

Comment: Exactly why it shouldn't :) An app bar uses an entire edge of a single display, not part of it.

Comment: but nVidia actually have the taskbar using 1/3 of my 3 monitors (which are treated as a single display.

Comment: But as you said "...and has been causing issues with fill screen apps.". Doesn't this back up the idea that it's a hack and is fundamentally broken?